# Maven on Windows 7 without admin rights - mvn.bat not trusted to download from web

Tags: windows, maven, windows-security

I work as a software engineer in a company that cannot give me local administrator rights on my Windows 7 workstation.  To avoid the month-plus SLA and hassle of teaching a tech support person how to install software that I need to do my job, I find myself getting creative by installing tools to my local Users directory and user specific environment variables where needed, but I am currently running into a problem with Maven not being able to download ANYTHING from ANY repository it seems.

From the command line I am simply doing:

> mvn -U clean

At the very first line I see it hangs here:

> Downloading: http://repo.mavan.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom

The build failures with a Connection timed out message.

I can copy this url into my browser window and download the POM file effortlessly.  If I had to guess what the problem might be:

1. It is that I am a limited user that downloaded a Zip file from the internet and copied its contents into my Users directory.  By default UAC will view these folders from the Internet source with a Low trust and will not allow the Low trust mvn.bat batch file to connect and download from an HTTP source.
2. The corporate anti-virus is blocking network access to this batch file.

I am not sure how to deal with either of these situations.  Is there a way to configure or tinker Maven around this limitation or am I going to have to sit and wait for over a month with nothing to do until a tech support guy can install maven for me?

**EDIT:** *I didn't think I needed to state this but please only provide an answer that won't get me fired and prosecuted.  Hacking the OS is an unacceptable solution.*

Comment: If you are really working in a company which didn't support you to get your work done this is hard. Furthermore if you are working with Maven you should have a companay repository manager which you should have been connected to and of course you need to configure Maven to use it (settings.xml). Apart from that i assume you are behind a proxy which can't access the internet directly without appropriate permission which you have to configure. If this has not been done during your on-boarding process this company is really weird.